# How to interpret google chrome cache data?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, hex

[image]

I went through my chrome cache at "chrome://cache/"

I understand that the far left side is just a reference to that row of addresses

The middle are values (3C, 13, 00, etc) are values representing 1 byte in hex notation (UTF-8)

I don't understand what the corresponding right side refers

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right side just represents the values of the middle (hex notation) in ASCII.

Comment: so "##" in hex notation can go up to values of 255, ASCII has values up to 255 as well. But whats with all the "........." periods though

Comment: Like "3C" in hex notation equivalent for ASCII is "<"    (decimal value 60).  But it shows up as a period "."

Comment: Because ASCII reserves the first 32 codes for control characters, they are not characters. Example 3C ('<') 13 (Carriage Return) 00 (Null) and so on.

Comment: ah okay I see now. http://www.ascii-code.com/ . Would you happen to know if carriage return is equivalent to `\n` for windows excel / google spreadsheet programs (for paragraph text in a cell). question is a bitofftopic though